# $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $H^{1}(\Omega)$, for a Lipschitz domain?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary, for example the unit cube $(0,1)\times...\times(0,1)$.

Is it true that for any $u\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, there exists a sequence $u_{j}\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ converging to $u$ in $H^{1}(\Omega)$?

If the boundary is smooth then the result can be found in many textbooks.

Any references are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: If you meant $C^\infty_c((0,1)^n)$ then no, you can't approximate $1$ with a $C^1$ function vanishing at the boundary. If you really meant $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$ then sure, send $f \in H^1([0,1]^n)$ to its corresponding piecewise $H^1$ function on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and let 
$f_k(x) = f( (1-\frac1k)x +\frac{1}{2k})$, $\phi \in C^\infty_c([-1,1]^n), \int \phi = 1,\phi_k(x) = k^n \phi(kx),g_k = f_k \ast \phi_{4k}$

Comment: @reuns Thanks so much. Did you mean that first we extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Why don't you take the convolution to $f$, instead of considering the modified $f_{k}$?

Comment: Try with $f$ constant $=r$ on $[0,1]^n$, we want the smooth transition $0 \to r$ to be outside $[0,1]^n$. If I replace $f_k$ by $f$ I get $f \ast \phi_k(0) = r/2^n$. For a more complicated $\Omega$ the idea is similar except that we need some approximate identifies to decompose $f$ in $\sum_j f \psi_j$ where each $f \psi_j$ is supported on a small cube.

Comment: @reuns Thank so much. I got your idea. For a general domain, we don't have this nice translation so we need to require a bit information on the boundary so that we can (locally) map it to cubes. You wrote that "can't approx. 1 with a $C^{1}$ vanishing at the boundary functions"; are you mentioning the Poincare inequality here?

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to the existence of an extension operator: Take $\Omega'=B_r(0)$ with $r$ large such that $\bar\Omega \subset \Omega'$. Then there is a continuous extension operator $E:H^1(\Omega)\to H^1_0(\Omega')$ with $(Eu)|_\Omega = u$. Now $C_c^\infty(\Omega') $ is dense in $ H^1_0(\Omega')$.

Now let $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, then $Eu\in H^1_0(\Omega')$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega')$ with $\| Eu - \phi\|_{H^1(\Omega')}\le \epsilon$. This implies $\| u - \phi\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\le \epsilon$. Since $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ as well, we get the denseness result.

Comment: I don't quite get your idea. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks. So if there exists such an extension then we have our approximation. My concern is how we construct such an extension for a given domain?

Comment: This is a standard result for Sobolev spaces. Please refer to some textbook. I do not have a book here. I think this is both covered by Evans or Adams.